# How to change Singleton Pattern before initialisation

Tags: java, design-patterns, initialization, switch-statement

```
public class PlayerSingleton {

private static PlayerSingleton player;   
private String playerName;

private Weapon weapon;

Weapon stockMP5 = new MP5Weapon();        //Making a new weapon called stockMP5 from MP5weapon Class
Weapon sniper = new SniperRifleWeapon();  //Making a new weapon called sniper from SniperRifleWeapon Class
Weapon shotgun = new ShotgunWeapon();  //Making a new weapon called shotgun from Shotgun Class

private PlayerSingleton(Weapon weapon, String pN) {
    this.weapon = weapon;
    playerName = pN;
}

public void chooseWeapon(String choice) {
    switch (choice) {
        case "MP5":
            weapon = new MP5Weapon();
            break;
        case "Sniper":
            weapon = new SniperRifleWeapon();
            break;
        case "Shotgun":
            weapon = new ShotgunWeapon();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("No Attachment found!");
    }
}

public static PlayerSingleton getInstance(Weapon choice, String n) {
    System.out.println("Choose Weapon to play the with: ");
```

// HERE I am looking to allow the player to choose the weapon before  the singleton class initiallises below. To let the player play with their gun and not change it throughout the game.

```
    if (player == null) {
        player = new PlayerSingleton(choice, n);
    }
    return player;
}

public void chosenWeapon() {
    System.out.println(weapon.getDescription()
            + " Weight of Player: " + playerName + " gun: " + weapon.weight() + " base damage: " + weapon.damage());
}

public void addBasicAttachment(String attachment) {
    switch (attachment) {
        case "sight":
            weapon = new BasicSight(weapon);
            break;
        case "silencer":
            weapon = new BasicSilencer(weapon);
            break;
        case "stock":
            weapon = new BasicStock(weapon);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("No Attachment found!");
    }
}

public void addGoodAttachment(String attachment) {
    switch (attachment) {
        case "sight":
            weapon = new GoodSight(weapon);
            break;
        case "silencer":
            weapon = new GoodSilencer(weapon);
            break;
        case "stock":
            weapon = new GoodStock(weapon);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("No Attachment found!");
    }
}

public void addGreatAttachment(String attachment) {
    switch (attachment) {
        case "sight":
            weapon = new GreatSight(weapon);
            break;
        case "silencer":
            weapon = new GreatSilencer(weapon);
            break;
        case "stock":
            weapon = new GreatStock(weapon);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("No Attachment found!");
    }
}
```

How do I go about allowing the player to choose the weapon before initialising the playerSingleton getInstance method?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edited:

```
public static Weapon chooseWeapon(String choice) {
        switch (choice) {
            case "MP5":
                return new MP5Weapon();
            case "Sniper":
                return new SniperRifleWeapon();
            case "Shotgun":
                return new ShotgunWeapon();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
public static PlayerSingleton getInstance(String choice, String n) {
        System.out.println("Choose Weapon to play the with: ");

        Weapon weapon = PlayerSingleton.chooseWeapon(choice);
        if (player == null) {
            player = new PlayerSingleton(weapon, n);
        }
        return player;
    }
```

The main:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" ------------------------------------ ");
        System.out.println("       Text based Shooting Game       ");
        System.out.println(" ------------------------------------ ");
        System.out.println("Please Enter your name before Beginning*");
        String name = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Thank you for joining this Adventure " +name);
   
        
        Weapon weapon = PlayerSingleton.chooseWeapon(name);   
        PlayerSingleton player = PlayerSingleton.getInstance("MP5",name);
        player.chosenWeapon();
```

Additional edit:
The Weapon class

```
public abstract class Weapon {
    String description = "Unknown Weapon: ";
    
    
    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }
    //public abstract int bulletCount();
    public abstract double weight();
    public abstract double damage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner approach would be to make the `chooseWeapon` method static, and to return the weapon:

```
public static Weapon chooseWeapon(String choice) {
    switch (choice) {
        case "MP5":
            return new MP5Weapon();
        case "Sniper":
            return new SniperRifleWeapon();
        case "Shotgun":
            return new ShotgunWeapon();
        default:
            System.out.println("No Attachment found!");
            return null;
    }
}
```

then on `getInstance` do:

```
public static PlayerSingleton getInstance(String choice, String n) {
    Weapon weapon = PlayerSingleton.chooseWeapon(choice);        
    if (player == null) {
        player = new PlayerSingleton(weapon, n);
    }
    return player;
}
```

The call to the getInstance:

```
 System.out.println("Choose Weapon to play the with: ");
 String choice = scanner.next();
 PlayerSingleton player = PlayerSingleton.getInstance(choice, name);
 player.chosenWeapon();
```

Answer (score 1):

So one question is why do you want your player to be singleton? The player object  should be initialised with the Game object and that way you would never really need to say "new" Player.

Now if you are re-spawning the player and creating a fresh instance, you should consider adding a "reset" method in the player class

**If you must do "Singleton":**
As far as the routine to choose the weapon goes it would be cleaner to delegate it to another class "WeaponFactory". A static method may be a short term approach and is a pain to test and stub if you have automated tests  (guess these are usually not written when writing a game?) :P

Now when you have a WeaponFactory, you can have a weapon chooser class that prompts the user and invokes the desired factory (or method)to create a "Weapon" before trying to get an instance of the Player.

**Practically**: If you don't write a "setWeapon" method in Player class you would have achieved the goal of not allowing the Player's weapon to be changed unless the Player object is created and associated with the Game again.